# Continue session in Selenium cannot getAttribute()

Tags: selenium

I have created a session in Selenium, re-use it by getting the session id, local_url and put into a different session. That means the new session will continue the original session. Function `getAttribute()` does not work on the continued session but if I put it in the original session, it works fine. I only face the problem with `getAttribute()` while other selenium functions such as `getText()`, `getCss()` worked well.

This is the re-use code:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = createDriverFromSession(session_id, local_url);
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).getAttribute(attribute));
```

Output:

```
{message=unknown error: a.getAttributeNode is not a function
(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)}
```

Somebody please help me. Thanks!

Comment: What is `a`? Are you sure that you want `a.getAttributeNode` and not `a.getAttribute(attribute)`?

Comment: That's what make me curious. I only put `getAttribute(attribute)` to my code but the error shows like I want an `a.getAttributeNode()`. Looks like `getAttribute(attribute)` will automatically be converted to `a.getAttributeNode()` when I continue the old session.

Comment: Which version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: I'm using selenium 3.6.0

Answer (score 3):

I did face some issue -->  message=unknown error: a.getAttributeNode is not a function

As i started debugging more - I figured out - Chrome is not using W3C Codec. So i changed code to reflect accordingly. Changed capabilities as well.

```
new W3CHttpCommandCodec to new JsonHttpCommandCodec()
new W3CHttpResponseCodec to new JsonHttpResponseCodec()
new RemoteWebDriver(executor, new DesiredCapabilities()) to return 
new RemoteWebDriver(url,  DesiredCapabilities.chrome())
```

This worked for my sample. Using selenium version 3.14.0 But believe it shouldn't matter.

Comment: So this fixed my issue.as well.  For those wondering where this code goes, I was creating my own custom RemoteWebDrive object (so i could reattach to pre-existing Selenium sessions, instead of relaunching a new one every time)

The code belongs in there.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above worked for me, but I wanted to provide a little more context.

I originally looked for a way to re-attach to an existing Selenium session instead of opening a new one.  I found the `createDriverFromSession` method (below) from another article on the web (I can't find it to link it).  That article contained the code below.  I commented out the lines that needed changed from the answer above.

```
public static RemoteWebDriver createDriverFromSession(final SessionId sessionId, URL command_executor){
    CommandExecutor executor = new HttpCommandExecutor(command_executor) {

      @Override
      public Response execute(Command command) throws IOException {
        Response response = null;
        if (command.getName() == "newSession") {
          response = new Response();
          response.setSessionId(sessionId.toString());
          response.setStatus(0);
          response.setValue(Collections.<String, String>emptyMap());

          try {
            Field commandCodec = null;
            commandCodec = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("commandCodec");
            commandCodec.setAccessible(true);
            // commandCodec.set(this, new W3CHttpCommandCodec());
            commandCodec.set(this, new JsonHttpCommandCodec());

            Field responseCodec = null;
            responseCodec = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("responseCodec");
            responseCodec.setAccessible(true);
            // responseCodec.set(this, new W3CHttpResponseCodec());
             responseCodec.set(this, new JsonHttpResponseCodec());
          } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        } else {
          response = super.execute(command);
        }
        return response;
      }
    };

//    return new RemoteWebDriver(executor, new DesiredCapabilities());
    return new RemoteWebDriver(executor, DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also finally resolved this issue. It was something to do with W3C like mentioned above.

I was doing this:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("w3c", false);
capabilities.setCapability("chromeOptions", chromeOptions);
```

I simply removed these caps and it worked as intended.