# Executing multiple JUnit tests using the same WebDriver object

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I currently have a number of web UI tests which share different tests (for instance, the `AccessOwnProfile`test and the `AccessAdminMenu` test both derive from the `Login`test.) So when I run the two separately in my suite, a new instance of WebDriver will be created for both tests, so the `Login` test will be ran multiple times, because `AccessOwnProfile`and `AccessAdminMenu` both extend `Login` test, like so:

```
public class AccessOwnProfile extends Login {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        super.test();
        ...
    }
```

This is not good because if `AccessOwnProfile` and `AccessAdminMenu` are both used in my `TestSuite`, `Login` will be executed twice which is pointless. Ideally, I'd like to be able to only have to run the `Login` test once.

This isn't necessarily difficult, I only need to remove the `extends` in my test classes so every test is truly isolated. However every test still expects to pick up where the previous one left off. 
So I need to be able to keep the same instance of WebDriver for my entire `TestSuite`.

Basically what I want to do is to be able to run multiple JUnit tests that pick up from where the other left off, on the **same browser instance**. Basically, after a test, I wouldn't close the web browser and open a new one for the new test as I do right now. I'd just reuse the browser that's already opened. 
I'm not entirely sure how to do this and where this would be configured. I cannot pass a webdriver instance to my test classes in my `TestSuite`.

From my previous tests, it appears to me that each new instance of WebDriver keeps the same session from the previous one, meaning I could easily close the browser after every test and open it again for following tests. However I don't know if this is a reasonable expectation. It also means I can't just pick back up easily from the previous test's ending page, which is a bit of a problem. The only way I can think of how I would do this would be to write the current page URL into a temp file on `tearDown()`, and then, on the following test's `setUp()`, open that file and access the saved URL.

There has to be a better way.

### EDIT: To clarify:

As it stands, I have divided different tests into multiple smaller tests so I can reuse code.

Imagine a `EditAvatar` test. You need to login and access your profile first.

Imagine a `EditUsername` test. You need to do that as well.

Instead of repeating those tasks which can be tests in and of themselves, I made them separate tests that these two tests inherit from.

The way i put it in place is that:

- `AccessOwnProfile` extends `Login`;
- `EditAvatar` extends `AccessOwnProfile`;
- `EditUsername` extends `AccessOwnProfile`;

and so on

That means in my Test Suite, if I run `EditUsername` and `EditAvatar`:

- `Login` will be played twice
- `AccessOwnProfile` will be played twice

To save on time I'd like to be able to use just one instance of the browser for the entire suite. That way I don't have to `Login` all over again for every test that requires access to a user panel for instance, because all I'll have to do is run my `Login` test once, and then I'm logged in for the rest of my TestSuite, I don't have to worry about repeating that particular task for each test.

Comment: your needs some kind of a strange but ok. do you run them in parallel or not?

Comment: no they are ran linearly. How are my needs strange? is there a better way to test website functionality?

Comment: then i dont know how your issues could appear. you initialize your driver and then work with it until all your tests completed and then `close()` it. Why you need to **run multiple JUnit tests that pick up from where the other left off, on the same browser instance** ? i guess you have some architectural problems with project structure.

Comment: I will explain myself more clearly in the OP

Comment: try to use `Cucumber` so you could easily construct test structure of steps that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the exact same problem as you. Closing and reopening the WebDriver for every test was a no-go for me. So I digged the internet and I found a [solution by Tarun Lalwani](https://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium-java/) (Scroll down to Attempt 3 for the solution).

He basically found a way to reuse the WebDriver by extracting its drivers (e.g. GeckoDriver, ...) URL and SessionID which than can be used to create a new instance of a RemoteWebDriver that communicates with the same previous driver.

In addition, if you are using ChromeDriver this said solution might not work because Chrome is not using W3C Codec ([as user2590117 stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53056366/11360567)) like the RemoteWebDriver in the above solution. So just follow the [fix of user2590117](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53056366/11360567) and you should be good to go.

To pass the drivers URL and SessionID between tests, I serialized both using [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) with some custom JsonSerializer objects, which worked just fine and which I unfortunately can't share because I did it for work.

Comment: I personally managed to get this working by making my `driver` object static and linking the various tests together in my suite. I still might move to your answer if my "solution" gives me any issues in the future, so i'm marking it as correct.